# Форматирование номера телефона в форме input при его вводе

Tags: javascript, php

Функция формы ввода телефона:

```
function get_type_tel($field){
   return '<input type="tel" '.$this->required.' '.$this->placeholder.' name="'.$this->slug.'" id="'.$this->slug.'" value="'.$this->value.'"/>';
}
```

Пробовал сделать через маску JS:

```
<script>
   $('input[name="vash_telefon_20"').mask('+7 (999) 999-99-99');
</script>
```

Находил несколько в интернете масок, но по всем выдаёт ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'mask')`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: " но по всем выдаёт ошибку" --- Потому что для mask нужен плагин jquery....который как раз и делает эту самую работу

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery-and-masked-input-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Подключил через id input и всё заработало:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#vash_telefon_20").mask("+7 (999) 999 9999");
  });
</script>
```